# What does it mean - "x bit decimal number"?

Tags: binary, decimal, digits, digital

What does it mean - "x bit decimal number"? Is it decimal number with x digits or a number whose value can be put in x bit binary digits?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is the code problem in this question?

Comment: What is the context of this question?